# R error | Vectors calculations returns the wrong matrix size | Non-conformable arrays

Tags: r, matrix-multiplication, manova

I am trying to calculate Within And Total Sum of Squares and Cross-Product Matrices (W) in one-way MANOVA. 
I have a treatment matrix **tm**:

```
 n x1 x2
 1  6 7
 1  5 9
 1  8 6
 ...
 2  3 3
 2  1 6
 2  2 3
 ...
 3  2 3
 3  2 3
 3  5 1
 ...
```

I also have each individual observations in their own variables, for example:

```
 x111 = x[1,1]
 x112 = x[2,1]
 ...
```

that are also in the variables that create vectors:

```
# creating vectors

t11 = c(x111, x111_2) # 6,7
t12 = c(x112, x112_2) # 5,9 
t13 = c(x113, x113_2) # 8,6
t14 = c(x114, x114_2) # 4,9
t15 = c(x115, x115_2) # 7,9
t21 = c(x211, x211_2) # 3,3
t22 = c(x212, x212_2) # 1,6
t23 = c(x213, x213_2) # 2,3
t31 = c(x311, x311_2) # 2,3
t32 = c(x312, x312_2) # 5,1
t33 = c(x313, x313_2) # 3,1
t34 = c(x314, x314_2) # 2,3

>dput(t11)
c(6,7)
```

I am trying to calculate W (Within And Total Sum of Squares and Cross-Product Matrices).

The means are

```
> x1 # treatment 1
[1] 6 8

> x2  # treatment 2
[1] 2 4

> x3  # treatment 3

[1] 3 2

> x # overall mean

     X1 X2
[1,]  4  5
```

The code I have is:

```
W = (t(t11)-t(x1))*(t11-x1)
+(t(t12)-t(x1))%*%(t12-x1)
+(t(t13)-t(x1))%*%(t13-x1)
+(t(t14)-t(x1))%*%(t14-x1)
+(t(t15)-t(x1))%*%(t15-x1)
+(t(t21)-t(x2))%*%(t21-x2)
+(t(t22)-t(x2))%*%(t22-x2)
+(t(t23)-t(x2))%*%(t23-x2)
+(t(t31)-t(x3))%*%(t31-x3)
+(t(t32)-t(x3))%*%(t32-x3)
+(t(t33)-t(x3))%*%(t33-x3)
+(t(t34)-t(x3))%*%(t34-x3)
```

The result I get is:

```
Error in (t(t11) - t(x1)) * (t11 - x1) + (t(t12) - t(x1)) %*%  : 
non-conformable arrays
```

When I isolated each statements, I got this:

```
> (t(t11)-t(x1))%*%(t11-x1)
      [,1]
 [1,]   1
> (t(t12)-t(x1))%*%(t12-x1)
     [,1]
[1,]    2
```

Why do these statements evaluate to 1x1 matrices? When I calculate 2x1 and 1x2 operations (subtraction and multiplication) manually, I get 2x2 for both. [Here](http://www.calcul.com/show/calculator/matrix-multiplication_;2;1;1;2?matrix1=[[%220%22],[%221%22]]&matrix2=[[%220%22,%221%22]]&operator=*) is an online calculator

Comment: Could you post the full equation for `W` (it cuts off with `...`)? Also, could you post `dput(x)` so we know exactly the object you're working with?

Comment: @mickey I've changed the code to create arrays separately (t11, t12, etc.) rather than accessing them by index. I now have a "non-comforable arrays error".

Comment: On the first line for W, do you mean to be doing matrix multiplication? And thanks for posting more of the data you're working with, but it is still difficult to replicate exactly what you're doing. It will be much easier to help you if you gave all the objects you're using.

Comment: @mickey I've edited the question, but I know why is it non-conformable - the matrices evaluate to different sizes, like 1x2 and 1x1, instead of 4x4 (when calculating manually). How do I make them calculate into 4x4?

Comment: Where does this 4x4 matrix come from? It seems unexpected since it looks like you're working with a bunch of 1x2's.

Comment: @mickey because I am multiplying by a transpose. [0 1]` * [0 1] manually adds up to [0 0 0 1]`

Comment: That's not accurate. [0 1]' * [0 1] is 1x1. [0 1] * [0 1]' is 2x2.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/184892/discussion-between-feyzi-bagirov-and-mickey).

Answer (score 0):

It can be confusing sometimes when working with vectors in R and you want to do matrix multiplication. A vector in R (say, `x = c(1,2)`) is printed like it might be a row vector, but R treats it as a column vector.

With that in mind, to get the 2x2 matrix you want, do

```
t11 = c(6, 7)
x1 = c(6, 8)
(t11 - x1) %*% t(t11 - x1)
```

No need for too many transposes.